# Django queryset filter and aggregate max, then put the max value in a variable

Tags: python, django

In a Django view I run the follow code in order to get the maximum value for the "position" column, where the "groupMain_id" is equal to 10:

```
lastposition = BlockMain.objects.filter(groupMain_id = 10).aggregate(themax=Max('position'))

testvar=lastposition

#Result
# {'themax': 3}
```

How can I assign the value "3" to the variable "testvar"?
If I use testvar=lastposition.themax I receive the error:

> Exception Type: AttributeError Exception Value: 'dict' object has no
>   attribute 'themax'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastposition` is a `dict`. Get its value by using `lastposition.get('themax', None)` or simply `lastposition['themax']`.

Note, however, that the latter can raise a `KeyError` if the Key does not exist, while the `get` method does not.